# ¿Cómo puedo resolver esta validación de una caja de texto?

Tags: entrada

Buen día... Estoy en un proyecto de MVC Y mi problemita esta en que necesito validar input numérico y no lo he podido implementar. Mi funcion es:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.solo-numero').keyup(function () {
                this.value = (this.value + '').replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
            });
        });
```

Comment: Hola, supongo que es javascript, pero podrías agregar el tag correspondiente al lenguaje? usa el botón [edit] si necesitas agregar información a la pregunta. De paso, lee [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tienes un ejemplo, es algo sencillo, aplica la expresion regular cuando se escribe en el input

```js
$('.solo-numero').on('input', function () { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="solo-numero" value="" />
```

Comment: y otra forma usando el <script type="text/javascript"> ...

Comment: @PaulGuerrero  `<script type="text/javascript"> $('.solo-numero').on('input', function () { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
}); </script>` esto es jquery, entonces tienes que agregar dicha libreria

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.solo-numero').on('input', function () { 
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" class="solo-numero" name="algo">


</body>
</html>
```

Espero que te funcione si algo me comentas.

Comment: Si presiono una tecla y la dejo presionada deja ingresar texto

Comment: @Dacoso ya lo solucione

Comment: Se debe comentar que realiza y que puede ayudar a solucionar, Revisar [answer].